# Wordpress - separate ajax responses from a single form method

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress

I am getting form input and making and AJAX call to get two separate custom post types. The main function of the page is to get a list of courses, which can be filtered by department(custom taxonomy) and grade, as well as a search function. The courses are a custom post type. The second part is to also get the staff members associated with the department and display them in a separate area on the page. Staff members are also a custom post type.

At present I always get the courses response from the AJAX call showing in both the course area and the staff area.

AJAX Calls

```
    function course_filter() {
        var filter = $('#course-filter');
        $.ajax({
            url: filter.attr('action'),
            data: filter.serialize(),
            type: filter.attr('method'),
            success: function(data) {
                $('#course-response').html(data);
            }
        });
        return false;
    }

    $( document ).ready(function() {
        course_filter();
    });

    $('#apply-course-filter').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        course_filter();
        course_staff_filter();
    });

    // Prevent Enter Submit on Course Search
    $('#course-search').keypress(function(event) {
        if( event.keyCode == 13 ) {
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    });

    function course_staff_filter() {
        var filter = $('#course-filter');
        $.ajax({
            url: filter.attr('action'),
            data: filter.serialize('department-filter'),
            type: filter.attr('method'),
            success: function(data) {
                $('#course-staff-response').html(data);
            }
        });
        return false;
    }
```

Course Results

```php
function filter_courses() {
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'course',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'orderby' => 'slug',
        'order' => 'DESC',
    );

    if( isset( $_GET['grade-filter'] ) && ( $_GET['grade-filter'] != " " ) ) :
        $grade = sanitize_text_field( $_GET['grade-filter']);
        $args['meta_query'] = array(
            array(
                'key' => 'grade',
                'value' => $grade,
                'compare' => 'LIKE',
            )
        );
    endif;

    if( isset( $_GET['department-filter'] ) && ( $_GET['department-filter'] != " " ) ) :
        $args['tax_query'] = array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'department',
                'field'    => 'id',
                'terms'    => $_GET['department-filter'],
            )
        );
    endif;

    if( isset( $_GET['search'] ) ) :
        $search = sanitize_text_field( $_GET['search']);
        $query = new WP_Query( array(
            'post_type'  => 'course',
            'posts_per_page' => -1,
            'orderby'    => 'title',
            'order'      => 'ASC',
            'tax_query'  => $args['tax_query'],
            'meta_query' => $args['meta_query'],
            's'          => $search,
        ) );

    else :

        $query = new WP_Query( $args );

    endif;


    if( $query->have_posts() ) :

        while( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); ?>

        <div class="course-card">
            <!-- <?php echo get_post_type(); ?> -->
            <h4><?php echo $query->post->post_title; ?></h4>
            <div class="course-content">
                <?php the_content(); ?>
                <p class="grade"><strong>Grade Level:</strong> <?php the_field('grade'); ?></p>
                <?php   ?>
            </div>
        </div>

        <?php endwhile;

        wp_reset_postdata();

    else :

        echo '<p>Sorry, we could not locate what you were searching for.</p>';

    endif;

    die();
}
add_action( 'wp_ajax_coursefilter', 'filter_courses' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_coursefilter', 'filter_courses' );
```

I would like to get two separate AJAX calls from the data from the form.

Answer (score 0):

first 
if would like to get two separate AJAX
then you need two call functions for ajax

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    course_filter();
course_staff_filter();
});
```

or as you have

```
$('#apply-course-filter').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    course_filter();
    course_staff_filter();
});
```

after
you need separate ajax and handler functions

```
function course_filter() {
....
        url: filter.attr('action'),// separate course handler AJAX
...
}

function course_staff_filter() {
....
        url: filter.attr('action'),// separate staff handler AJAX
....
}
```

Staff Results

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_stafffilter', 'filter_staff' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_stafffilter', 'filter_staff' );
function filter_staf() {
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'your_staff_posttype',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'orderby' => 'slug',
    'order' => 'DESC',
);
//do your filter
//.....



    $query = new WP_Query( $args );




if( $query->have_posts() ) :

    while( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); ?>

    <div class="staff-card">
        <!-- <?php echo get_post_type(); ?> -->
        <h4><?php echo $query->post->post_title; ?></h4>
        <div class="staff-content">
            <?php the_content(); ?>
            <?php //do as you want  ?>
        </div>
    </div>

    <?php endwhile;

    wp_reset_postdata();

else :

    echo '<p>Sorry, we could not locate what you were searching for.</p>';

endif;
die();
}
```

and as you have

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_coursefilter', 'filter_courses' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_coursefilter', 'filter_courses' );
```

Comment: Alright, I have this but I think the crux of the problem, that maybe I wasn't very clear on is that I need the staff to go to one area or division on the page and the course to go to another area or division on the page.